# Setting anchor on page on refresh/pageload

Tags: filter, anchor, href, pageload, page-refresh

I have a page that contains an area about halfway down the page that filters properties (custom post type) by Price, Bedrooms, and Sq Ft. The filter works fine, however upon filtering the properties (by clicking any of the filters), the page refreshes back to the top of the page, causing the user to have to scroll down the page to see the filtered results. I am wondering how I would go about attaching an anchor to those links so the page refreshes to the filtered posts area of that page so the user does not have to scroll down again. Would this be done by firing an event via JS or how exactly would this be done?

Ive attached my link below. All and any insight is much appreciated!

Scroll down to "View Quick Move in Homes" to view properties and filters - http://www.daybreakutah.com/find-a-home/

Answer (score 0):

1) Give an id to the tag you want to scroll down to:

```
<h2 id="filter1">
```

2) In your hrefs, add #filter1 (or whatever you called it) to the end of the URL:

```
<a href="http://www.daybreakutah.com/find-a-home/#filter1">
```

Comment: how would I go about adding #filter to my php? '<?php
                    foreach( array('desc'=>$inventory_price) as $asc_desc => $asc_desc_name ) {
                        echo '<a class="sort-btns-left" href="';
                        echo add_query_arg( array( 'orderby' => inventory_price, 'order' => $asc_desc)
                        );
                        echo "\">Price</a>";
                        }
                ?>'

Comment: got it! - 
                <?php
                    foreach( array('desc'=>$inventory_price) as $asc_desc => $asc_desc_name ) {
                        echo '<a class="sort-btns-left" href="';
                        echo add_query_arg( array( 'orderby' => inventory_price, 'order' => $asc_desc)
                        );
                        echo("/#filter");
                        echo "\">Price</a>";
                        }
                ?>  thanks so much!